# bower install lists package config but doesn't install package

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I'm on a fresh Debian 8 platform trying to install bower packages.

Here's the config:
nodejs: v6.2.1
npm: v3.9.3
bower: v1.7.9

I'm currently working as root, so I add the --allow-root option (which has never been a problem).

Everything seems to fine. But when trying to install a package (either bower install [package name] or bower install (bower.json)) bower seems to install what's listed in bower.json and prints what looks like the the package config but doesn't actually install the package.

```
bower install ngmaps
...
{
  "level": "action",
  "id": "validate",
  "message": "0.1.0 against git://github.com/monospaced/bower-qrcode-generator.git#v0.1.0",
  "data": {
    "endpoint": {
      "name": "qrcode-generator",
      "source": "git://github.com/monospaced/bower-qrcode-generator.git",
      "target": "v0.1.0"
    },
    "resolver": {
      "name": "qrcode-generator",
      "source": "git://github.com/monospaced/bower-qrcode-generator.git",
      "target": "v0.1.0"
    },
    "canonicalDir": "/root/.cache/bower/packages/66daec2cebc85c0406043bff1212efc1/0.1.0",
    "pkgMeta": {
      "name": "qrcode-generator",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "main": [
        "js/qrcode.js",
        "js/qrcode_UTF8.js"
      ],
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "components"
      ],
      "homepage": "https://github.com/monospaced/bower-qrcode-generator",
      "_release": "0.1.0",
      "_resolution": {
        "type": "version",
        "tag": "v0.1.0",
        "commit": "64e898f180fbd76aa2740be41124d219aa735f0c"
      },
      "_source": "git://github.com/monospaced/bower-qrcode-generator.git",
      "_target": "v0.1.0"
    }
  }
}
...
, {
  "type": "input",
  "message": "Answer",
  "name": "prompt",
  "level": "prompt"
}
```

This particular package is an app dependency, but obviously not ngmaps.
The dependencies should be installed in a vendor directory, but this directory is empty.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: I played around a bit and found out that when removing the .bowerrc file everything seems to work.
I would like to keep it though...

The file looks like this:

`{
  "directory" : "app/vendor",
  "json"      : "bower.json"
}`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a real answer but after I removed the json field from the file everything worked fine.
Now the file looks like this:

{ "directory" : "app/vendor" }